# What happens when the same application from different server tries to connect to the always on primary server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, client, hadr

In our environment we have an always on availability group and the reporting server is acting as a secondary replica with Synchronous Mode, manual failover. XSLT report editor that is a vendor application will connect to the application server which in turn connects to the database server. The application server (separate server)  connects to the listener to serve client connections. My question is if I set up a separate application server just for the XSLT report which in turn connects to the reporting, now will there be any problems if the reporting server for some disaster recovery becomes the primary where the Client application and the XSLT application will both  connect, both the application is same  that is installed on separate server one for client another for the xslt report.

I am not comfortable to set up transactional replication which is an additional overhead. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the application has connection string of `applicationIntent=ReadOnly` then listener will redirect that to the secondary - provided your secondary allows read connection.

Comment: The application settings only asks for the database server name or IP there is no read only intent option and the reporting replica will be read only

Comment: Then your application will always connect to Primary.

Comment: So the client app connects to the listener, and the XSLT report connects directly to the secondary reporting server right? Since the reporting server is a manual failover server, you will manually failover to this one if disaster happens, and then your XSLT reporting and Client App will be sending queries to the same server, that will increase I/O.

Comment: I am fine  with the increased I/O as in the Always on availability group there are 4 Replica- 2 with Synchronous Automatic Failover, 1 Reporting server onsite manual failover synchronous mode and 1 Disaster Recovery server offsite.

Comment: There is a rare possibility of the reporting server becoming the primary because the reporting replica is onsite and if the primary site goes offline i will fail over to offsite  Disaster Recovery Replica but again if there is chance of this server becoming the primary i can turn off the reporting application. Just wanted to make sure that same application from two different server can connect to the same database server without any conflicts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a technical standpoint, there are no problems with multiple applications, running on multiple different machines, connecting to the same SQL Server instance.

If you experience the failover scenario that you described, it's possible that the reporting workload will interfere with your other workloads from a *performance* standpoint.

In other words, all the long read queries your reporting app does could block queries coming from your other apps.  And in general the reporting app queries will require CPU time and I/O time that is normally solely used by the other app.

It's hard to say without more detail whether this would just slow things down a little, or bring your whole app grinding to a halt due to blocking or resource contention.